# Not getting delete Icon in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

EDIT,
             I am working on a application which have two entry points. 
         One for **Background service** (Alternate Point & Auto Startup) & 
         Second one for application **UI handling** (Main Entry Point).

Now the issue is, I am **not able to find delete option**.  Even I am not able to delete the application 
        from **(Options >> Application)**.
        

         I have attached the screen shoot for the same.

[image]

Please explain me why I am not getting the delete icon.

        I got a [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141815/application-cannot-be-deleted-when-has-multiple-entry-points) that states that it's a **known issue**.

Comment: +1.  thanks for separating this :)

Comment: thanks buddy for the support ..now let me know , How I can sort out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you install apps using javaloader, or via developing tools, you can't uninstall it but with javaloader.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..but i am getting this scenario every time.